# Can't make SQL query from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I Can't make a SQL query for:

I have the following tables:

1. **User** which have two columns namely: *user_id* and *user_name*.
2. **Group** which has three columns namely : *id*, *group_name* and *created_date*.
3. **Records** which has five columns namely : *id*, *group_id*, *user_id*, *record_content* and *record_type*.
4. **record_user** which has three columns namely : *user_id*, *record_id* and *liked*

Now I want a query which could execute on all 4 tables something like:

**select user_id, user_name, group_id, record_content**

Also I need in this table - the liked field for each record based on user_id (which mean that this user is authenticated).

The thing that I try to get all messages(records) of definite group and information regarding like of each record by user which is currently reading this messages(records).

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Why is both record_id and user_id located in record_user?  Is there a reason why user_id can't be derived from Records via record_id?

Comment: Please format your question properly. And try to provide some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT User.user_id AS user_id,
       User.user_name AS user_name,
       Group.id AS group_id,
       Group.group_name AS gorup_name,
       Records.record_content AS record_content,
       record_user.liked AS liked
FROM User
JOIN Records ON User.user_id = Records.user_id
JOIN Group ON Group.id = Records.group_id
JOIN record_user.record_id ON Records.id
GROUP BY User.user_id,
         Group.id;
```

The `AS`'s are not required, they just are useful for giving the output fields more convenient names.  You can change them to pretty much whatever you want.

Please see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp for more on `JOIN`'s - look for the Venn diagram as well as read the explanation.

The `GROUP BY` clauses may not be needed, but you have not explained how you wish the output to be sorted and grouped, so I have chosen those as a suggestion.

Note : In the future it will help if you present us with sample data and desired output.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.